# If the TV is not on sale, I will not buy it?

Tags: propositional-calculus

If the TV is on sale, I will buy the TV.

The TV is not on sale.
$\therefore$ I will not buy the TV.

$p$: The TV is on sale.

$q$: I will buy the TV.

First statement above: $p\implies q$

Second statement above: $\lnot p$

Third statement: $\lnot q$

Logical statement: $[(p\implies q) \land \lnot p] \implies \lnot q$

Is this a valid argument? Why or why not?

Comment: you ask if this statement is a tautology?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am asking.

Comment: The argument "$p \to q$ and $\lnot p$, therefore $\lnot q$" is **not** *valid* and the formula $[(p \to q) \land \lnot p] \to \lnot q$ is **not** a *tautology*.

Comment: To show that the formula is not a tautology, draw a truth-table: the entry for $p$ False and $q$ True will satisfy the *antecedent* of the [conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional#Truth_table) but not the *consequent*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try drawing a truth table

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
p&q&p\implies q&\lnot p&\lnot q&(p\implies q) \land \lnot p&((p\implies q) \land \lnot p)\implies\lnot q\\
\hline
0&0&1&1&1&1&1\\
\hline
0&1&1&1&0&1&\color{red}{0}\\
\hline
1&0&0&0&1&0&1\\
\hline
1&1&1&0&0&0&1
\end{array}
$$